# ReactJS setState is not working,not updating, not doing async

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have button when its click it whill do alert popup showing value of this.state.sidemenu_state using ToggleSideMenu.the first click its shows "show", but then the problem is when the **button clicked the second time**, its **still show the old value "show" not "1"**

```
class OptionButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sidebar : new SideBar()
        };
    }

    handleClicked =()=> {
        this.state.sidebar.ToggleSideMenu();
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <button class="" onClick={this.handleClicked}></button> 
        );
    }
}
OptionButton.contextType = GlobalParamContext;

class SideBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sidemenu_state : "show"
        };
    }

    ToggleSideMenu() {
        this.setState({sidemenu_state : "1"});
        alert(this.state.sidemenu_state);
    }
    
    render() {
        return(
            <div class="sidemenu"></div>
        )
    }
}

class TopBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div class="bg-slate-900 h-11">
            <OptionButton />
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The state updated, you just logging a stale value due to closures, log the same state in componentDidUpdate.

Comment: im not trying to do logging, the problem is alert(this.state.sidemenu_state); is showing the old state.

as example if i use this.state.sidemenu_state as condition its gonna get old value instead new value even if i click the button hundred times

Comment: Oh I didnt notice, you actually not using React API in the right way, you need to mount the component if you want the state to work, calling `new SideBar()` won't register the component as React.Node, you need to go over the tutorials for examples

Comment: so i have to move the this.state.sidemenu_state to OptionButton ? sorry im totally new using react